# Navigation Menu in a list. How to make entire li the clickable link, not just text

Tags: css, html

https://jsfiddle.net/jomot/nttuccay/5/

So I want to entire `<li>` to be clickable, not just the text.

Code is included in the jsfiddle.

Thanks to anyone that responds :)

Comment: Move padding from `li` to `a`, and add `display:block` to the latter. https://jsfiddle.net/nttuccay/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Enclose" the buttons with a `block` and the padding should be inside.

```
a { display:block; padding: 8px; } 
a:link {color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;} 
a:visited {color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;} 
a:hover {color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;} 
a:active {color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;}
```

Easy peasy!

Answer (score 0):

Make your anchors `display:block` and move the padding to the anchor from the `li`

```
.menu li a {
  display:block;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nttuccay/14/)

> [`display:block`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) turns the `a` into a block level element, which takes up the entire real-estate of its parent.

```css
.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li {
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    background-color: #2D74B4;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    text-align: center;
}
.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #0099cc;
}
.menu li a {
    display:block;
    padding: 8px;
}

a:link {color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;}
a:visited {color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;}
a:active {color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
 </ul>
  </div>
```